# Qt, thread safety regarding UDPlink

Tags: c++, qt

If I have a Qt's UDPlink and a writeBytes function like this:

```
void UDPLink::writeBytes(const char* data, qint64 size)
{
    // Broadcast to all connected systems
    for (int h = 0; h < hosts.size(); h++)
    {
        QHostAddress currentHost = hosts.at(h);
        quint16 currentPort = ports.at(h);
        socket->writeDatagram(data, size, currentHost, currentPort);
    }
}
```

Here the socket is a UDP socket.
Is this function thread safe? That is can I call the writeBytes() function from 2 different threads?

Answer (score 2):

The only 2 parts that may be not thread safe:

one is that is that datagrams may get interleaved (which happens anyway with UDP so no worries)

The other thing is that `QUdpSocket::writeDatagram` is not thread safe. So you either need to synchronize access to socket with a mutex or using the signal/slots or make a socket for each thread.

making it thread safe can be easy:

```
//make it a slot or invokable
void UDPLink::writeBytes(const char* data, qint64 size)
{
    if(QThread::currentThread() != thread())
    {
        QByteArray buff(data, size);//makes a copy pass in a QByteArray to avoid
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "writeBytes", Q_ARG(QByteArray, buff));
        //this forward the call to the thread that this object resides in if the calling thread is different.
        return;
    }
    for (int h = 0; h < hosts.size(); h++)
    {
        QHostAddress currentHost = hosts.at(h);
        quint16 currentPort = ports.at(h);
        socket->writeDatagram(data, size, currentHost, currentPort);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain for simpleminded what is done in first conditional?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO, QUDPsocket is not thread-safe but is reentrant which means you cannot call QUDPSocket->writeDatagram/writeBytes from 2 different thread using the same instance **but** you can call call QUDPSocket->writeDatagram/writeBytes **from separate instances** of QUDPSocket

Comment: Why not? QUdpSocket::writeDatagram() calls QNativeSocketEngine::writeDatagram() which calls QNativeSocketEnginePrivate::nativeSendDatagram(). All functions have no affect to the internal states of related objects. Finally nativeSendDatagram() calls sendto(), which is threadsafe in POSIX according to several discussions here.

Comment: @VladimirKunschikov because the documentation doesn't say it's thread-safe. You didn't check the windows implementation either.

Comment: I am simply saying that topic starter is asking not about QUdpSocket whole object but about one and only writeDatagram() method which can be safely called from several threads simultaneously. You don't have to create different sockets for different destinations.